# MySQL image ignores volume configuration of docker-compose.yml

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Using the official MySQL Docker image, I don't understand how to mount the data directory to a specifc point on the host. [The Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/5836bc9af9deb67b68c32bebad09a0f7513da36e/5.7/Dockerfile) of the image sets

```
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
```

so database data should be stored "somewhere" on the host. I want to be more specific in my docker-compose file, so I tried the following:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
  volumes:
    - ./database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Starting with `docker-compose up` everything works fine, but the ./database/mysql directory on the host stays empty, whereas /var/lib/mysql in the container contains data. Is there a problem in my configuration? Or do I misunderstand how to use volumes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`docker-compose` will always try to preserve data volumes, so that you don't lose any data within them. If you started with a data volume, then changed to a host volume, you may still get the data volume.

To correct this, run `docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -f`, which will remove your containers and your data volumes (this will erase any data in your data volumes). On the next `docker-compose up`, you should see it using the host volume.

Edit: As of Compose 1.6 you can run `docker-compose stop -v` instead of the two commands above.

Comment: You are right, that's the point. Thanks for solution + explanation!

Comment: Thanks! Save my day!